# Access google analytics data from python api

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-api

I am trying to access google analytics demo accounts data from python api

i have created service account api credentials but my understanding is that we need to add this service account credential as a user in google analytics demo account.

The problem is in google analytics demo account i do not have the permission to add users

Is there any other way i can access this data from python

Comment: if I understand this post in Google help [Demo account](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6367342?hl=en)  - `You cannot use the demo account with the Analytics Reporting API`. You can see it in `Limitations`

Comment: oh sorry i defiantly missed that. I have one more question is Analytics reporting api different than Analytics API, if yes can i use that on demo account ?

Comment: frankly I don't know if `Analytics Reporting API` means `Analytics API` or not. I never try to use Python to get data from `Analytics API`. And I have account on `Analytics API` so I wouldn't have to use `demo account` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to programatically access data stored in Google Analytics you would use one of the Google analytics APIs,

- Google Analytics core reporting api   (universal analytics)
- Google Analytics api                  (universal analytics)
- Google Analytics data api             (GA4)

The [Demo account](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6367342?hl=en) for google analytics is used for viewing Google analytics data and testing it.  It does not offer access via any of the Google analytics apis.

What I have personally done in the past is create my own demo account by inserting data into a standard google analytics account though the measurement protocol then the data can be accessed using the Google Analytics API of your choice.

So to answer your question you cant use the google analytics api to access data on the Google analytics demo account.

Comment: That's a really good way but unfortunately my use case requires me to have original data from demo account

Comment: The point is that you will need to create your own demo account this is what i did.  I have mentioned to the team it would be nice to have a demo account that worked with the API but that was several years and they have not added anything yet.  I can bring it up again when i speak to them next.